# Redirecionamento com .htaccess, da pasta www para a pasta public do projeto

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, redirecionamento

Preciso configurar um redirecionamento através do .htaccess.

O meu "DOCUMENT_ROOT" (utilizando Apache e PHP) está configurado para "www", a qual é a raiz base do projeto, mas o index.php esta na pasta "public".

Não sei se tem a ver com versões, mas o tutorial do cara diz o seguinte:

Na pasta www, um .htaccess com o conteúdo abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

E na pasta public, um .htaccess com o conteúdo abaixo:

```
Option -Indexes
```

No entanto, como muitos tutoriais, não funcionou!! O que me leva a pensar que é algo a ver com versão, porque na apresentação dele funciona!

O meu projeto estou simulando localmente, então a minha url é "http://localhost/".

Que deveria ser redirecionada para "http://localhost/public/index.php" e ainda deveria continuar mostrando "http://localhost/" no navegador.

Encontrei várias "soluções", tanto aqui quanto externo, mas nenhuma funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

No seu exemplo, a RewriteRule esta correta, se ele não encontrar o file no diretório atual, ele vai direcionar para o index.php e o url vai receber todo o conteúdo da requisição original.

PORÉM, você diz que o .htaccess deve estar rodando na sua localhost, faltou informar:
-Seu servidor (APACHE, pelo conteudo) está com o MOD_REWRITE habilitado?
-Também está preparado para ler os arquivos de configuração .htaccess nos diretórios onde você está colocando-os?
-Não existe o arquivo no diretório www, pois se existir o arquivo requisitado ele usa o arquivo, e não o re-escrito....

Comment: Esqueci de comentar!!
Mas.. creio que se refere à linha:
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Bom, eu já havia descomentado ela, e... não funcionou!!!

No caso o diretório www, é o meu diretório raiz, onde esta o .htaccess de redirecionamento.

Comment: seu mod_rewrite tá fncionando, depois de ter descomentado é preciso reiniciar o apache para funcionar.....

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: dá uma lida nesse howto do apache, pois ele vai te auxiliar se você precisar habilitar o arquivo, pois ele pode estar configurado com outro nome, ou não configurado.....

Comment: vou ler, mas.. fiz o procedimento como é, ou seja... habilitei a linha e reiniciei o apache.. ainda limpei cache, atualizei a pagina.. e.... nada!!! estranho!!